# Creating the Custom Verified Email Page URL & Custom Reset Password Page URL

Tags: backand

Using Back&, I'm working on creating the "Custom Verified Email Page" & the "Custom Reset Password Page" to work with my app so that users can verify emails at signup and request password resets via email.

Does anyone have an example of what these pages should be doing?  I know the URL receives a token for the transaction but what are we suppose to be doing with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I see that I can use the Backand SDK with the resetPassword method to use the token along with a user supplied new password to finish out the password reset.

Comment: But I still haven't figured out how to work the email verification. Any help or hints please?

Comment: I'm looking for examples as well.

Comment: Ever found out how this is achieved?

Comment: No, I haven't figured this out yet. There is a direct method of resetPassword to use with a user supplied new password but as far as verifying email, I still haven't found the method to do that. Was going to work on it again in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything with it (look under security -> security acctions -> newUserVarification. Backand handles all of it for you. Make sure you specify a **Custom Registration Page URL** and the **Custom Verified Email Page URL**.  If you don't have the registration url, the link in the email to confirm you as a new user will always send you to a blank page that reads,  "SignUp redirect url was not supplied in configuration".

Comment: I see the newUserVerification but all that does is send an email to the user with the link. The link goes to my website where I'm to have supplied pages to handle verification and password resets where the user receives an email with a link that has a token. What I'm asking for is what to do with that token?

So if I have in my Security >> Configuration >> Custom Verified Email Page URL as   http://www.myappdomain.com/sign-in.html

So what code should I have in  sign-in.html to handle the variables & token that are passed to that? Similarly with the Custom Reset Password Page?

Comment: Please remember, I'm doing this as a hybrid app so my full app is not at that website.